# R rollapplyr to calculate 10-day sum in xts zoo class

Tags: r, xts, zoo, quantmod, rollapply

I am new to R, I would like to calculate the below formula in the zoo xts class object.

formula:
10-day sum of [(close- open)/(high-low) *volume] / 10-day sum of volume

Input df:

```
df <- getSymbols("0005.HK", auto.assign = FALSE, src = "yahoo")
```

First I create a new column in the df

```
df$oneday <- (Cl(df) - Op(df)) / ((Hi(df) - Lo(df)) * Vo(df))
```

Then I tried to write a function for the above formula

```
df$tenday <- rollapplyr(df, 10, function (x) df$oneday/Vo(x), by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)
```

However, Error comes out,

```
Error in array(ans, c(len.a%/%d2, d.ans), if (!is.null(names(dn.ans)) ||  : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Anyone can help, thank you.

Comment: can you post some data?

Comment: df <- getSymbols("0005.HK", auto.assign = FALSE, src = "yahoo") yup, sorry.

Comment: `df$1day` has length 2622 and `Vo(x)` has length 10. The division `df$1day/Vo(x)` cannot be performed because the two vectors have different lengths